# How to get Cucumber-JVM to work with Gradle and Guice?

Tags: java, configuration, gradle, guice, cucumber-jvm

Cucumber-JVM and Gradle don't play along nicely.
This is well known, and a [workaround](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/java-gradle) has existed for some time.

However, I can't get said workaround to work with some more advanced tests using Guice as a DI container: Cucumber does not pick up the Guice module configured in the properties file, and maybe doesn't even pick up the file itself, causing singletons to be configured multiple times.

My project conforms to standard layout (`src/test/java`, `src/test/resources`), with Cucumber's `cucumber-guice.properties` residing in the root of the resource folder.
Inside my IDE of choice, IntelliJ IDEA, the tests run fine.

Do you know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by applying the scopes directly via [annotations](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes).